# How do i submit rDNS request at AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My Email account is getting bounced and receipting mail domains are asking to set rDNS. However, I don't know how can I submit rDNS request in AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted their support and found that we can request them using the below link.

https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true